# Looking for the best way to redirect all my sites within IIS to the same domain with www in front of it

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

first of all: This is my very first post here. If I do something wrong please tell me and I will try to fix it.

I have multiple sites running in my IIS.
My problem is that each site is reachable with domain.com and www.domain.com. But always redirect to domain.com.
Other subdomains working well (beta.domain.com, shop.domain.com).

I found following url rewrite rule [here (http://www.mickgenie.com/redirect-domain-without-www-to-www-with-web-config/)](http://www.mickgenie.com/redirect-domain-without-www-to-www-with-web-config/):

```
<rule name="www redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="www redirect https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This seems to be an endless loop.
I got these results:
domain.com -> www.domain.com with error: too many redirects
www.domain.com -> domain.com with error: too many redirects
beta.domain.com -> beta.domain.com
shop.domain.com -> shop.domain.com

Is there any way to stop this? I tried this:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www." negate="true" />
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a simpler way as solution or maybe I'm completly wrong?!
In any case it also bother me that you have to do it separately for each site.
Is there a way to set a default rule for all sites within IIS?

I know there are many posts for this or nearly this theme using .htaccess file but I don't found anything about exactly this question. I'm very sorry if it is a Similar or doublicated question.

I'm glad about any help

Greetings from Cologne
Sebastian